# Get tab width on windows with WINAPI?

Tags: winapi, windows-console

I need to format character-perfect text in the Windows console, so I need to get the tab size to handle tabs. I've looked at the [Console functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073(v=vs.85).aspx) but it does not seem to contain such information.

Is there a way to get the tab size, or is something that's not exposed by the WIN API?

Comment: There is no option to change it.  It is 8 like it was on the teletypes of old.  If you want it perfect then you have to use spaces.

Comment: The console uses tab stops every 8 columns, so a tab character doesn't have a constant size.

Comment: @eryksun I know that it is not actually size, it is "distance between every stop", but I thought the question makes more sense this way.

Comment: If you don't want to hard code the tab-stop width, you could query the cursor position after printing `\r\t`.

Comment: @eryksun Thanks, this is a fine idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to hard code the tab-stop width, you could query the cursor position after printing `\r\t`. For example:

```
int get_tab_stop_width()
{
    int tab_stop_width = -1;
    HANDLE h = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0,
        NULL, CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER, NULL);
    if (h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        DWORD n;
        if (WriteConsoleW(h, L"\r\t", 2, &n, NULL)) {
            CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO info;
            if (GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(h, &info))
                tab_stop_width = info.dwCursorPosition.X;
        }
        CloseHandle(h);
    }
    return tab_stop_width;
}
```

This should return 8 on all versions of Windows, assuming the process is attached to a console.